# Refused opml file by slack RSS feed

Tags: rss, slack

I'm trying to subscribe to some RSS feeds using slack. However I get the following message:

`That doesn't look like a valid RSS/Atom feed.`

Here is the rejected file: https://gist.github.com/mpagli/e84d0e4d7d7efd4def9cec696555b8a4

I have already subscribed to several other feeds without any problem. For instance the following feed gets accepted: https://github.com/rushter/data-science-blogs/blob/master/data-science.opml

The two files seem very similar in their syntax and both get validated with the same warnings using https://validator.w3.org/feed/

Any idea on why the feed list gets rejected?

Comment: The error message said that it didn't look like RSS. Since the file is an OPML file, it seems likely that the problem is with one or more of the URLs in it.

Comment: I tried removing all but one URL that I know valid, still the same error.

Comment: Any luck on this so far?

Comment: No, I just gave up and switched to a plugin: https://slack.com/apps/A0N9YUELR-rss-fox